# How to print only even numbers in a JS array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cant figure out how to print only even numbers from an array:

`var arrayAgeList = [27, 35, 135, 45, 25, 28, 24];`

I have tried a few variations, but they dont work:

```js
while (i < arrayAgeList.length) {
  for (i = 1; i < arrayAgeList.length; i++) 
    if (i % 2 === 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you do something? please add your code, you tried.

Comment: refresh, should be there now

Comment: `arrayAgeList.forEach(n => n % 2 === 0 && console.log(n));`

Comment: @FilipZafran At what point are you printing anything?

Comment: print meaning as in show on screen, Print in Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a function to achieve this and to print you'll need to do something like a console log

```js
var arrayAgeList = [27, 35, 135, 45, 25, 28, 24];

function even(list){
  for(var i of list){
    if (i % 2 === 0){
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}

even(arrayAgeList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `i` and take a single `for` loop and start with zero, because the index is zero based.

For the check, you need the value isntead of the index and if `true` make an output with the value.

```js
var arrayAgeList = [27, 35, 135, 45, 25, 28, 24],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < arrayAgeList.length; i++) {
    if (arrayAgeList[i] % 2 === 0) console.log(arrayAgeList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var evenNumbers = arrayAgeList.filter(currentNumber => currentNumber % 2 === 0)
```

Comment: Can you add some context to explain how this will answer the question, instead of code-only answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` in order to filter the array and remain only even ages, then you can just print it.

```js
const arrayAgeList = [27, 35, 135, 45, 25, 28, 24];

const even = num => num % 2 === 0;

const evenAges = arrayAgeList.filter(even);

evenAges.forEach(age => console.log(age));
```